# JavaFX PixelReader Alpha-Channel not working

Tags: java, javafx, rendering, pixel

```
public class Loader {

    public static byte[] loadImage(String path) {
        Image image;
        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream(path));
            int width = (int) image.getWidth();
            int height = (int) image.getHeight();
            byte[] data = new byte[width * height * 4];
            image.getPixelReader().getPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getByteBgraPreInstance(), data, 0, width * 4);
            return data;
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return null;
    }

}


@Override
    public void render(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        gc.getPixelWriter().setPixels(x++, 0, 819 ,720, PixelFormat.getByteBgraPreInstance(), data, 0, 819*4);
        gc.getPixelWriter().setPixels(400, 0,819 ,720, PixelFormat.getByteBgraPreInstance(), data, 0, 819*4);
    }
```

Hello, at the moment i have a Problem with the PixelWriter/PixelReader from JavaFx. I try to read the Pixel from an Image and store it in a Buffer, after that I want to render it to the Screen. But the Image contains now no Alpha Value, so there are nor transparent Pixels. I searched for a few hours on the Internet but I can't find an answer. Maybe there is a problem with the Format.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There may very well be a problem with the format. Of the 4 formats supported by the `Image` class, only two have mechanisms for defining transparency - GIF, which may have a transparent color (so either alpha=1 or alpha=0), and PNG which may contain a full alpha channel. If you are reading a BMP or JPG file you will have no alpha values. Even when reading a PNG file, if the original file has no alpha channel you won't see any variation in the alpha of different pixels.

Comment: Already checked the PNG file, it has an Alpha Channel. Forgot to say that i am aware of only reading Images with Alpha Channel.But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it (because you did not provide a complete and executable example) but I think your problem is that you use a pixel format with pre-multiplied alpha. Try again with one of the simple rgb formats without pre-multiplication.